# Swift - Adding a timer to a action in touchesBegan

Tags: ios, swift, action

I have this code in the touchesBegan method

```
let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:0.5)
myObstacle.runAction(action, withKey:"action")
```

What I'd like to do is have the action wait .5 seconds before the user is able to rotate the obstacle again.

Is there an easy way of doing this in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a timer property and a boolean flag in your class.

```
var timer: NSTimer?
var timerIsRunning = false
```

In your `touchesBegan` method check if the timer is running. If so, just return from the method.

If not, set `timerIsRunning` to true and start the timer with its interval of 0.5 seconds. Set the timer's action to a method which simply sets `timerIsRunning` back to false and invalidates the timer.

```
func touchesBegan(..) {
    if self.timerIsRunning {
        return
    }

    // your touchesBegan code here
    let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:0.5)
    myObstacle.runAction(action, withKey:"action")

    // start the timer
    self.timerIsRunning = true
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("timeUpdate:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func timerUpdate() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.timerIsRunning = false
}
```